# Django Rest Framework - Si no existe un registro igual insertar datos de lo contrario no insertar

Tags: python, djangorestframework

Estoy trabajando en Django Rest Framework y no se como puedo evitar un registro si uno de los campos coincide con un campo que estoy enviando por POST, es decir, tengo un campo nombre y quiero que al insertar un campo nombre que ya exista en la base de datos me rechace la petición.

Esta es la estructura que tengo, especificamente no se que colocar en el argumento de `filter` para que coincida con lo que estoy enviando. Cualquier aporte sera de gran ayuda!

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def distritoEscolarNuevo(request):
    serializer_class = DistEscolarSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer_class.is_valid:
        
        if TbledcDistritoEscolar.objects.filter(nb_distrito_escolar='No se que colocar aqui'):
            return Response({
                'msg':'Este registro ya existe, no puede repetirse'
                })
            
        serializer_class.save()
    
    return Response(serializer_class.data)
```

Comment: Este tipo de validaciones conviene realizarlas a nivel del modelo, en lugar de a nivel de alguna vista en particular. Así, te recomiendo usar una constraint de tipo `UniqueConstraint` la cual levantará una excepción de tipo `IntegrityError` que podrás manejar apropiadamente en tu vista.

Comment: Entiendo, pero a nivel de codigo como puedo agregar la validacion de un IntegrityError?

Comment: `Try`-`Except IntegrityError` (El cual puedes importar de `django.db`)

Comment: Gracias!! voy a intentarlo!